# Auto run executable after save in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I want to use visual studio code for C programming and I want to automate the procedure of saving -> compiling -> running. At the moment I have MinGW installed and using the C/C++ extension I achieved the saving and compiling using Ctrl+S (I changed the shortcut of compiling) but in order to execute I need to go to the cmd prompt and execute the program.

Is there any way I can, using one button, achieve this?

Comment: If it's really that important for you, why don't you just get a full-featured IDE like [MSVS Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs) or [Eclipse/CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/)?

Comment: Visual studio is heavy and eclipse? Nah...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I came to the aswer is to define my shortcuts

```
[
   {
       "key": "ctrl+s",          
       "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" 
   },
   {
       "key": "ctrl+d",          
       "command": "workbench.action.tasks.test" 
   }
]
```

Then in tasks.json

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
   "command": "cmd",
   "isShellCommand": true,
   "args": ["/C"],
   "showOutput": "silent",
   "tasks": [
       {
           "taskName": "saveNcompile",
           "suppressTaskName": true,
           "isBuildCommand": true,
           "args": ["gcc main.c -o main.exe"]
       }, {
           "taskName": "execute",
           "suppressTaskName": true,
           "isTestCommand": true,
           "args": ["main.exe"]
       }
   ]
}
```

And now using ctrl+s save and compile and ctrl+d execute.

Comment: please will u tell me where to store first file

Comment: How about java?